# What is the proper name of this PCB "slide blade" spring female connector?

Tags: pcb-design, connector

I have an appliance with two PCBs, which can be connected to each other by a "slide blade spring" connector (my term for that).

I want to buy this connector, but all the "spring" styled receptacle connectors I found are for attaching *wires*, not a counterpart "blade" male connector.

I have attached an image from the female and male respectively.

[image: female]
[image: male]

Comment: Suggestion: Take a photo looking square on into the connector in the top photo with a neutral screening material behind it, then use google etc image search

Comment: Nice idea, I will try and update here.

Answer (score 3):

I call them [Power Blade PCB sockets terminals](https://www.google.com/search?q=Power+Blade+PCB+sockets+terminals&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj6sZThlN-BAxWmId4AHWXmAnAQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Power+Blade+PCB+sockets+terminals&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DXggNY1YgDYLySA2gBcAB4AIABYIgB1gSSAQE4mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=Fs4eZfrOF6bD-LYP5cyLgAc&bih=937&biw=1920).

Comment: Only male connectors I find under "power blade" names, or insulated stacked arrays of receptacles. 

Seems everybody used to put the blade (male) on the PCB, and use the "shoe" type connector as floating female (like with batteries).

Answer (score 0):

There are similar products in the EMI shielding space as well:

[SMT RFI Shield Clips | Harwin](https://www.harwin.com/connectors-hardware/emc-shielding/smt-rfi-shield-clips/)

None of them seem large enough, nor thru-hole, to be an exact match for the pictured parts, but these may be useful for other applications.

There may also be fuse holders in interesting shapes, though anything made to hold a blade that size is of the curled-sides / quick-connect style I think.  Something to clip onto a much thicker tab, instead of a round cartridge fuse, would do for example.

Comment: Nearest find, indeed. Unfortunately the profile of shield clips is too low to securely fix a blade, and it comes in a double-receptacle (long) config, which would need to be manually cut. And as you write it's SMT.